# How to generate a html page from a template and datas

Tags: php, html

I want to generate some static html files from a template and a large set of datas.

This "set" is an uploaded json (ie a blob that became a file) that I want to read in the generated page using javascript, so I was thinking about inserting it as a string into a `<script>` tag of the page (something like `<script>json=MYJSON</script>`, I don't know if it's the best way to achieve this ...).

Now the question is how to copy a file (template) and add/edit a part of it (a tag) in the new file...

It seems that the simplest way is to use `copy` and give GET parameters to the template wich get it with a php code that echoes the tag .. for example here with a 'name' GET parameter :

```
copy('http://localhost/site/template.php/?name=' . $name, '../public/new_file.html');
```

It works fine, but the problem is that I can't pass a large data using this method, so how to achieve this ?

Comment: Just an idea: you could avoid passing many data to the PHP just loading the large set of data directly from template.php (using the name parameter to decide what set to load)

Comment: If by "load" you meant a javascript xhr the goal is to avoid it.. Finally I read the file with 'file_get_contents' in template.php and insert it into a script tag, it seems to work..